# Change data in PDF from HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

I want to change text in my PDF document from webpage. It will be some sort of diploma. I have large illustration and the text on it. There will be two empty rows - "Name" and "Date". I wonder if there's a way to change the "name" on pdf? I know, that there is an interactive PDF, but i dont know how to instert variables to the document from HTML. Anyone can help me?

Or perhaps you know better way to do this? I have two variables from JS or from Cookies (date and name), and want to generate a diploma. I have that illustration, fancy font and text. I was trying to do that with generating PDF from HTML, but it was problem with parsing a giant picture, and it was trying to open a pop-up, but I cant do this like that. It must be on same page or new tab.

Comment: I at least know this can be done with PHP, so if you have accessibility to it try adding PHP as a tag.

Comment: I added the tag. I think the PHP will be good too

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is creating a new pdf, inserting the template and name and stuff. But I do not think it is possible with Javascript alone, but with an ajax call to your server. PHP for example got [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) library which is relatively easy to use.

Comment: I think AJAX would not be necessary. I will be saving data to cookies from flash app, then i will make PDF with TCPDF by using COOKIES as variables. Thanks for help, i will try this method.